# Remove the first element of a VBA array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Is there a way to remove the first element of an array in `VBA`?

Something like javascript `shift()` method?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no direct method in VBA but you can remove the first element easily like this:

```
'Your existing code
'...
'Remove "ReDim Preserve matriz(1 To UBound(matriz))"
For i = 1 To UBound(matriz)
  matriz(i - 1) = matriz(i)
Next i
ReDim Preserve matriz(UBound(matriz) - 1)
```

Comment: While this is a good answer and I am upvoting it as such, you could perhaps remark that if the goal is to have something like a queue then this would be a dreadfully inefficient way to implement it. Code that makes heavy use of things like this should probably be modified so as not to require it.

Comment: Note that there is a 0th element so the `For Each` will always report something for the first (0th) element.

Answer (score 4):

There is unfortunately not. You have to write a method to do it. One good example is http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?562928-Remove-Item-from-an-array

```
'~~> Remove an item from an array, then resize the array

    Public Sub DeleteArrayItem(ItemArray As Variant, ByVal ItemElement As Long)
    Dim i As Long

    If Not IsArray(ItemArray) Then
      Err.Raise 13, , "Type Mismatch"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If ItemElement < LBound(ItemArray) Or ItemElement > UBound(ItemArray) Then
      Err.Raise 9, , "Subscript out of Range"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = ItemElement To lTop - 1
      ItemArray(i) = ItemArray(i + 1)
    Next
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    ReDim Preserve ItemArray(LBound(ItemArray) To UBound(ItemArray) - 1)
    Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
    '~~> An error will occur if array is fixed
    Err.Raise Err.Number, , _
    "Array not resizable."

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to incorporate this subroutine in your code "as-is", be careful to change `lTop` to `UBound(ItemArray)`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string array, you could join, offset, and split again.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String

    Const sDEL As String = "||"

    vaSplit = Split("1 2 3 4", Space(1))
    sTemp = Join(vaSplit, sDEL)

    vaSplit = Split(Mid$(sTemp, InStr(1, sTemp, sDEL) + Len(sDEL), Len(sTemp)), sDEL)

    Debug.Print Join(vaSplit, vbNewLine)

End Sub
```

Returns

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Just for the sake of the art: it's always interesting to see other solutions avoiding loops (cf. my current approach) +1

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but a study on array addressing.

This code:
    ReDim Preserve matriz(1)
    matriz(1) = 5

Creates an array with two elements: 0 and 1 
UBound() returns 1

Here is some code that may help explore the issue:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
   Dim matriz() As Variant
   Dim x As Variant
   Dim i As Integer
   matriz = Array(0)

   ReDim Preserve matriz(1)
   matriz(1) = 5
   ReDim Preserve matriz(2)
   matriz(2) = 10
   ReDim Preserve matriz(3)
   matriz(3) = 4

   Debug.Print "Initial For Each"
   For Each x In matriz
       Debug.Print ":" & x
   Next x
   Debug.Print "Initial For i = 0"
   For i = 0 To UBound(matriz)
       Debug.Print ":" & matriz(i)
   Next i
   Debug.Print "Initial For i = 1"
   For i = 1 To UBound(matriz)
       Debug.Print ":" & matriz(i)
   Next i
   Debug.Print "remove one"

   For i = 1 To UBound(matriz)
     matriz(i - 1) = matriz(i)
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve matriz(UBound(matriz) - 1)

   For Each x In matriz
       Debug.Print ":" & x
   Next x

   Debug.Print "remove one more"
   For i = 1 To UBound(matriz)
     matriz(i - 1) = matriz(i)
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve matriz(UBound(matriz) - 1)

   For Each x In matriz
       Debug.Print ":" & x
   Next x
End Sub
```

Out:

```
Initial For Each
:0
:5
:10
:4
Initial For i = 0
:0
:5
:10
:4
Initial For i = 1
:5
:10
:4
remove one
:5
:10
:4
remove one more
:10
:4
```

Answer (score 1):

**No direct method, but sort of work around without loops :-)**

This approach uses an intermediate target range to

- [1] receive the array data (starting e.g. in cell `A10`) and
- ....    get them back as resized 2-dim datafield (counting from cell `A11` thus omitting the first element) and
- [2] transpose it back to a flat 1-dim array

**Example code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'Method: use temporary target range to restructure array
 Dim matriz() As Variant
 Dim rng      As Range
'[0.1] Assign same data set to array as in original post
 matriz = Array(0, 5, 10, 4)
          Debug.Print "a) original matriz(" & LBound(matriz) & " To " & UBound(matriz) & ")", Join(matriz, ", ")
'instead of:
'  ReDim Preserve matriz(0 To 3)
'  matriz(0) = 0: matriz(1) = 5: matriz(2) = 10: matriz(3) = 4

'[0.2] Set temporary range to memory
 Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A10").Resize(UBound(matriz) + 1, 1)
'[1] Write array data to range and reassign to matriz cutting first row
 rng = Application.Transpose(matriz)                    ' fill in array data (transposed to column)
 matriz = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(matriz), 1)    ' assign data to (2-dim) array omitting first row
'[2] Transpose back to flat 1-dim array
 matriz = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(matriz, 0, 1))
          Debug.Print "b) ~~>  new matriz(" & LBound(matriz) & " To " & UBound(matriz) & ")", Join(matriz, ", "),

End Sub
```

**Example output in VBE's immediate window (`Debug.Print`)**

```
a) original matriz(0 To 3)  0, 5, 10, 4
b) ~~>  new matriz(1 To 3)  5, 10, 4
```

---

//Edit #1 **Tricky alternative using combobox properties & methods**

```
Sub RemoveFirstElement()
    'a) Assign same data set to array as in original post
    Dim matriz() As Variant
    matriz = Array(0, 5, 10, 4)
        Debug.Print "a) original matriz (" & LBound(matriz) & " To " & UBound(matriz) & ")", Join(matriz, ", ")
    'b) Remove first element in matriz (note 0-based indices!)
    RemoveElem matriz, 0             ' << call help procedure RemoveElem
        Debug.Print "b) ~~>  new matriz (" & LBound(matriz) & " To " & UBound(matriz) & ")", Join(matriz, ", ")
End Sub
```

**Help procedure `RemoveElem`**

This help procedure profits from the integrated method `.RemoveItem` of a combobox control which you can get on the fly without need to create an extra userform *)

```
Sub RemoveElem(arr, ByVal elemIndex As Long)
    'Use combobox properties and methods on the fly (without need to create form)
    With CreateObject("Forms.ComboBox.1")
        'a) assign existing values
        .List = Application.Transpose(arr)
        'b) delete e.g. 1st element (0-based control indices!)
        .RemoveItem elemIndex
        'c) assign modified values to tmp array (losing 2nd dimension by transposition)
        Dim tmp As Variant
        tmp = Application.Transpose(.List)
        'd) decrement base by 1 (from 1 to 0) - optional
        ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To UBound(tmp) - 1)
        'e) overwrite original array
        arr = tmp
    End With
End Sub
```

**Example output in VBE's immediate window (`Debug.Print`)**

```
a) original matriz(0 To 3)  0, 5, 10, 4
b) ~~>  new matriz(1 To 3)  5, 10, 4
```

**Related links**

[Can I return a 0-based array from `ws.UsedRange`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938280/can-i-return-0-base-array-from-ws-usedrange-value/53950312#53950312)

`*)` I found the way to create a solo combobox at [Create an empty 2d-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568342/create-an-empty-2d-array) )

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a function "Shift", which behaves like the shift method in JS, and an example of the use of "Shift"

```
Sub tryShift()

Dim aRy As Variant, sT As Variant

aRy = Array("one", "two", "three", "four")

Debug.Print "Original array:"
For Each sT In aRy
Debug.Print sT
Next

aRy = Shift(aRy)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Array having been " & Chr(34) & "shifted" & Chr(34) & ":"
For Each sT In aRy
Debug.Print sT
Next

End Sub

Function Shift(aRy As Variant)

Dim iCt As Integer, iUbd As Integer

iCt = 0
iUbd = UBound(aRy)

Do While iCt < iUbd
    aRy(iCt) = aRy(iCt + 1)
    iCt = iCt + 1
Loop

ReDim Preserve aRy(UBound(aRy) - 1)

Shift = aRy

End Function
```

Output:

```
Original array:
one
two
three
four

Array having been "shifted":
two
three
four
```