# Delete value from array then resize

Tags: vba, excel

For reference, here is the whole code.

```
  Sub CalculateOutliers()

                Dim n As Long
                Dim mean As Double
                Dim SD As Double
                Dim k As Long
                Dim DataSet As Variant
                Dim LowConf As Double
                Dim HighConf As Double


            '--------------------------------------------------------
                DataSet = Selection.Value
            'Copies highlighted data into DataSet variable
            'Cell A1 is (1,1) Because it starts at 0 which is out of range
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
                n = Selection.CountLarge
            'Counts number of entries
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
             'DEFINES 95(LowConf) AND 99(HighConf) PERCENT CONFIDENCES BASED ON
             'SAMPLE SIZE

                If n <= 5 Then
                        LowConf = 1.72
                        HighConf = 1.76
                End If

                If n = 6 Then
                        LowConf = 1.89
                        HighConf = 1.97
                End If

                If n = 7 Then
                        LowConf = 2.02
                        HighConf = 2.14
                End If

                If n = 8 Then
                        LowConf = 2.13
                        HighConf = 2.28
                End If

                If n = 9 Then
                        LowConf = 2.21
                        HighConf = 2.39
                End If

                If n = 10 Then
                        LowConf = 2.29
                        HighConf = 2.48
                End If

                If n = 11 Then
                        LowConf = 2.36
                        HighConf = 2.56
                End If

                If n = 12 Then
                        LowConf = 2.41
                        HighConf = 2.64
                End If

                If n = 13 Then
                        LowConf = 2.46
                        HighConf = 2.7
                End If

                If n = 14 Then
                        LowConf = 2.51
                        HighConf = 2.75
                End If

                If n = 15 Then
                        LowConf = 2.55
                        HighConf = 2.81
                End If

                If n = 16 Then
                        LowConf = 2.59
                        HighConf = 2.85
                End If

                If n = 17 Then
                        LowConf = 2.62
                        HighConf = 2.9
                End If

                If n = 18 Then
                        LowConf = 2.65
                        HighConf = 2.93
                End If

                If n = 19 Then
                        LowConf = 2.68
                        HighConf = 2.97
                End If

                If n = 20 Then
                        LowConf = 2.71
                        HighConf = 3
                End If

                If n = 21 Then
                        LowConf = 2.73
                        HighConf = 3.03
                End If

                If n = 22 Then
                        LowConf = 2.76
                        HighConf = 3.06
                End If

                If n = 23 Then
                        LowConf = 2.78
                        HighConf = 3.08
                End If

                If n = 24 Then
                        LowConf = 2.8
                        HighConf = 3.11
                End If

                If n = 25 Then
                        LowConf = 2.82
                        HighConf = 3.14
                End If

                If n = 26 Then
                        LowConf = 2.84
                        HighConf = 3.16
                End If

                If n = 27 Then
                        LowConf = 2.86
                        HighConf = 3.18
                End If

                If n = 28 Then
                        LowConf = 2.88
                        HighConf = 3.2
                End If

                If n = 29 Then
                        LowConf = 2.89
                        HighConf = 3.22
                End If

                If n = 30 Then
                        LowConf = 2.91
                        HighConf = 3.24
                End If

                If n <= 35 And n > 30 Then
                        LowConf = 2.98
                        HighConf = 3.32
                End If

                If n <= 40 And n > 35 Then
                        LowConf = 3.04
                        HighConf = 3.38
                End If

                If n <= 45 And n > 40 Then
                        LowConf = 3.09
                        HighConf = 3.44
                End If

                If n <= 50 And n > 45 Then
                        LowConf = 3.13
                        HighConf = 3.48
                End If

                If n <= 60 And n > 50 Then
                        LowConf = 3.2
                        HighConf = 3.56
                End If

                If n <= 70 And n > 60 Then
                        LowConf = 3.26
                        HighConf = 3.62
                End If

                If n <= 80 And n > 70 Then
                        LowConf = 3.31
                        HighConf = 3.67
                End If

                If n <= 90 And n > 80 Then
                        LowConf = 3.35
                        HighConf = 3.72
                End If

                If n <= 100 And n > 90 Then
                        LowConf = 3.38
                        HighConf = 3.75
                End If

                If n <= 150 And n > 100 Then
                        LowConf = 3.52
                        HighConf = 3.89
                End If

                If n <= 200 And n > 150 Then
                        LowConf = 3.61
                        HighConf = 3.98
                End If

                If n <= 300 And n > 200 Then
                        LowConf = 3.72
                        HighConf = 4.09
                End If

                If n <= 400 And n > 300 Then
                        LowConf = 3.8
                        HighConf = 4.17
                End If

                If n <= 500 And n > 400 Then
                        LowConf = 3.86
                        HighConf = 4.32
                End If

                If n > 500 Then
                        MsgBox "Sample size cannot exceed 500."
                End If
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
                If n < 50 Then
                    k = Int(n / 10)
                Else
                    k = 5
                End If
            'determines k = number of possible outliers
            '--------------------------------------------------------

            Dim i As Long

            For i = 1 To k
            '--------------------------------------------------------
                mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataSet)
            'Calculates mean of Data Set
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
                SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(DataSet)
            'Calculates Standard Deviation of Data Set
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
                Dim Suspect As Double


                If (Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataSet) - mean)) > (Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DataSet) - mean)) Then

                    Suspect = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataSet)

                End If

                If (Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataSet) - mean)) < (Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DataSet) - mean)) Then

                    Suspect = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DataSet)

                End If
            'Defines what the most outlying value is
            '--------------------------------------------------------



            '--------------------------------------------------------
                Dim Retest As Boolean

                If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then
                    MsgBox "95% outlier: " & Suspect
                    Retest = True
                End If

                If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then
                    MsgBox "99% outlier: " & Suspect
                    Retest = True
                End If

                If Retest = True Then

            '--------------------------------------------------------
            Next i


            End Sub
```

Talking about this chunk of code, I need to delete Suspect from DataSet then shrink DataSet by 1 but I am not sure how to go about this. Is there a function that will delete the Max or Min value and is there a way to resize DataSet given that it is a variant?

```
                        Dim Retest As Boolean

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then

                            MsgBox "95% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then

                            MsgBox "99% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If

                        If Retest = True Then
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231734/remove-the-first-element-of-a-vba-array

Comment: Use [**`Select Case`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) instead of end number of **`End If`**.

Comment: To resize an array to exclude items, make a second array of the same dimensions, copy in the items you want to keep, then resize the second array using `Preserve` to eliminate the unused portion.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to sort the data, either in excel before reading it into the vba routine, or in vba [see for example Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx). With sorted data, you can remove outliers by changing array bounds, e.g. `DataSet(3) to DataSet(n-5)` has removed 2 outliers on the low side and 5 on the high side.

Hope that helps

Comment: Clever idea, I will look into it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement the solution (similar to @Tim's comment)

```
Sub calculateOutliers()
    Dim retest As Boolean, dataSet As Variant, n As Long, found As Range
    Dim lowConf As Double, highConf As Double, suspect As Double, tmp As Double
    Dim mean As Double, stdDev As Double, dataMin As Double, dataMax As Double

    retest = True
    While retest
        dataSet = Selection.Value
        n = Selection.CountLarge
        If Not IsEmpty(dataSet) Then
            updateConfidences dataSet, n, lowConf, highConf
            retest = False
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                mean = .Average(dataSet)
                stdDev = .StDev(dataSet)
                dataMin = .Min(dataSet)
                dataMax = .Max(dataSet)
            End With
            suspect = IIf(Abs(dataMax - mean) > Abs(dataMin - mean), dataMax, dataMin)
            tmp = Abs(suspect - mean) / stdDev
            Set found = Selection.Find(What:=suspect, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If tmp > lowConf Then
                With Selection
                    found.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    .Value = removeItemFromArray(dataSet, suspect)
                End With
                retest = True
            End If
            If tmp > highConf Then
                found.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                retest = True
            End If
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

---

```
'updates lowConf and highConf (byref)
Private Sub updateConfidences(ByRef dataSet As Variant, ByVal n As Long, _
                              ByRef lowConf As Double, ByRef highConf As Double)

    'DEFINES 95(LowConf) AND 99(HighConf) PERCENT CONFIDENCES BASED ON SAMPLE SIZE
    Select Case True
        Case n <= 5:   lowConf = 1.72:   highConf = 1.76
        Case n = 6:    lowConf = 1.89:   highConf = 1.97
        Case n = 7:    lowConf = 2.02:   highConf = 2.14
        Case n = 8:    lowConf = 2.13:   highConf = 2.28
        Case n = 9:    lowConf = 2.21:   highConf = 2.39
        Case n = 10:   lowConf = 2.29:   highConf = 2.48
        Case n = 11:   lowConf = 2.36:   highConf = 2.56
        Case n = 12:   lowConf = 2.41:   highConf = 2.64
        Case n = 13:   lowConf = 2.46:   highConf = 2.7
        Case n = 14:   lowConf = 2.51:   highConf = 2.75
        Case n = 15:   lowConf = 2.55:   highConf = 2.81
        Case n = 16:   lowConf = 2.59:   highConf = 2.85
        Case n = 17:   lowConf = 2.62:   highConf = 2.9
        Case n = 18:   lowConf = 2.65:   highConf = 2.93
        Case n = 19:   lowConf = 2.68:   highConf = 2.97
        Case n = 20:   lowConf = 2.71:   highConf = 3
        Case n = 21:   lowConf = 2.73:   highConf = 3.03
        Case n = 22:   lowConf = 2.76:   highConf = 3.06
        Case n = 23:   lowConf = 2.78:   highConf = 3.08
        Case n = 24:   lowConf = 2.8:    highConf = 3.11
        Case n = 25:   lowConf = 2.82:   highConf = 3.14
        Case n = 26:   lowConf = 2.84:   highConf = 3.16
        Case n = 27:   lowConf = 2.86:   highConf = 3.18
        Case n = 28:   lowConf = 2.88:   highConf = 3.2
        Case n = 29:   lowConf = 2.89:   highConf = 3.22
        Case n = 30:   lowConf = 2.91:   highConf = 3.24
        Case n <= 35:  lowConf = 2.98:   highConf = 3.32
        Case n <= 40:  lowConf = 3.04:   highConf = 3.38
        Case n <= 45:  lowConf = 3.09:   highConf = 3.44
        Case n <= 50:  lowConf = 3.13:   highConf = 3.48
        Case n <= 60:  lowConf = 3.2:    highConf = 3.56
        Case n <= 70:  lowConf = 3.26:   highConf = 3.62
        Case n <= 80:  lowConf = 3.31:   highConf = 3.67
        Case n <= 90:  lowConf = 3.35:   highConf = 3.72
        Case n <= 100: lowConf = 3.38:   highConf = 3.75
        Case n <= 150: lowConf = 3.52:   highConf = 3.89
        Case n <= 200: lowConf = 3.61:   highConf = 3.98
        Case n <= 300: lowConf = 3.72:   highConf = 4.09
        Case n <= 400: lowConf = 3.8:    highConf = 4.17
        Case n <= 500: lowConf = 3.86:   highConf = 4.32
        Case n > 500:  MsgBox "Sample size cannot exceed 500."
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function removeItemFromArray(ByRef initialArray As Variant, _
                                     ByVal suspect As Double) As Variant

    Const dex As String = "#,###.00000"
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, dim1 As Long, dim2 As Long, arrayCopy As Variant

    dim1 = UBound(initialArray, 1)
    dim2 = UBound(initialArray, 2)

    ReDim arrayCopy(1 To dim1, 1 To dim2)

    For i = 1 To dim1
        For j = 1 To dim2
            If Format(initialArray(i, j), dex) <> Format(suspect, dex) Then
                arrayCopy(i, j) = initialArray(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    removeItemFromArray = arrayCopy

End Function
```

[image][image]