# Excel VBA Dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba

I know we can write dynamic array 
My question is 
Can i write values 6*6 it will get me a 36 array

I want this to be saved in some cell as my values could be changed to 5*5 
Basically my array is dynamic i want each result to be saved

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some sample code or pseudo-code?

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by "saved in some cell"?

Comment: Are you trying to store an entire array into a single worksheet cell?

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you have an array

```
Dim Arr()
ReDim Arr(1 To 6, 1 To 6)
```

you can only change the last dimension eg

```
ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 6, 1 To 5)
```

but never the first one. Therefore what you ask for is not possible without loosing the data in the array.

The only workaround for that is to create a new array and move the data from the old array to the new one field by field.

Comment: Upvoted. Not really sure what OP wants, but this is a good point to consider.

Comment: @BigBen Not sure too ^^ but if that is what he tried to do, we can shorten the discussion completely because it's not possible, and he needs to change the approach completely.

Comment: FYI posted an answer with other workarounds to `ReDim` both dimensions in a 2-dim array; you might be interested especially in the advanced features of the `Application.Index` function :-) +1 @PEH

Comment: @T.M. Nice thoughts +1 :) Actually the `Index` solution is technically more like creating a new (smaller) array out of the old one and write it back into the old variable `v` rather than re-dimensioning the array. Even if that has the same result :) • Would be interesting to do some tests about speed of that workaround (or if pushing it into a range like your first idea is even faster).

Comment: Note that if you Dim an array as shown here it's fixed size and cannot be Redim'd (with or without Preserve). If you Dim it as a dynamic array `Dim Arr()` then size it with `ReDim Arr(1 To 6, 1 To 6)` then the commentary around Preserve is true.

Comment: As suggested I did some tests showing that the `Index` function prevails over the `Push to Range` method, i.e. it's roughly twice as fast: 100k rows are executed within 0.28 seconds, 500k in 1.45 secs and 1 million in 2,92 secs vs. 0.59, 2.97, 6,20 secs (whereas the workaround looping thru a newly built array is the fastest way, even 1M under 1 second - @PEH

Comment: @T.M. wow I didn't expect the loop to be the fastest ^^ Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

**Write 6x6 array values back to sheet as if redimmed to 5x5**

As far as I understand your intention, you want to 
 - save 2-dim array values to a range (referenced by a given top cell) and
 - to get rid of the upper boundary in *both* dimensions for reasons whatever.

If not added one by one, you might have gotten the original data from a sheet range as follows

```
Dim v                               ' provide for a variant array
v = Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(6, 6) ' assign all data to 1-based 2-dim array v
```

Note the fully qualified range reference via a sheet's `CodeName`, assuming basic data in a sheet 
with VBE Tool Window (Name) of e.g. `Sheet1`.

**Attempt 1 - resize the hosting target range to receive array v**

This would be the easiest way to get the needed values into the sheet, but 
with the disadvantage that you did'nt change the related array likewise, e.g.

```
With Sheet2
    .Cells.Clear            ' emptying any content in target sheet
    .Range("A2").Resize(5, 5) = v   ' start cell e.g. in A2 (leaving room for title row)
End With
```

To overcome this, you might want to copy to a temporary sheet and return the resized values only

```
    With Sheet2
        .Cells.Clear            ' emptying any content in target sheet
        .Range("A2").Resize(5, 5) = v   ' blueprint the entire array via a filtering bottle neck
        v = .UsedRange          ' resize the array, too :-)
    End With
```

**Attempt 2 - redim the original array**

In case you'd try to redimension the original array via ► `ReDim` or `ReDim Preserve`, 
PEH mentioned correctly, that it's only possible to *change the* **last dimension**, *e.g.*

```
ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 6, 1 To 5)
```

*but never the first one.*

**TL;DR**

The cited answer states as well:

> The **only** workaround for that is to create a new array and move the data
>     from the old array to the new one field by field.

Out of inquisitiveness I tried to find other workarounds.

**`[1]` Using the ► `Application.Index` function**

```
    v = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("row(1:5)"), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

or alternatively via procedure call `RD` (short for `ReDim`)

```
RD v, 5, 5
'...

Sub RD(Arr, UBnd1&, UBnd2&)
    Arr = Application.Index(Arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBnd1 & ")"), Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & UBnd2 & ")")))
End Sub
```

C.f. the advanced features and pecularities of the `Application.Index` function 
at [Insert new first column in array without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

**`[2]` Using a listbox'es `.List` property**

An alternative would be 
 - to redim an array in its 2nd dim, 
 - assign it to a ListBox.List created on the fly,
 - remove last rows and assign `.List` property back to the array

**Caveat:** the `.List` property returns a zero-based 2-dim array instead 1-based items
see [return 0-based array from UsedRange value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938280/may-i-return-a-0-base-array-from-ws-usedrange-value/53950312#53950312)
to reflect the method.

**`[3]` Possible memory methods avoiding too much loops, e.g. via `MemCpy` or `CopyMemory`**

►Would be interested in any feed back knowing a valid answer, could pose a new question if wanted.