# Handle an array to avoid errors

Tags: excel, vba

In userform1, I have the following code

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ListBox2
        If .ListCount = 0 Then MsgBox "You Have To Select At Least One Column", vbExclamation: GoTo Skipper
        ReDim aCols(0 To .ListCount - 1)
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            aCols(i) = "[" & ListBox2.List(i, 0) & "]"
        Next i
    End With
Skipper:
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

and in standard module I declared aCols as public

```
Public aCols
```

if listbox2 has no items then aCols became Empty while if there are items the aCols became an array ..
Then in another code I am confused of how to avoid errors

```
If UBound(aCols) > -1 Then
```

This works fine if aCols is not empty but I encountered errors if aCols is Empty .. How to deal with both cases
Simply I need to avoid the errors and deal with aCols either it is empty or either it is an array.

Comment: [`IsArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isarray-function) might be helpful.

Comment: `IsArrary()` and `IsEmpty()` can both be used to address this issue.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59568342/2165759)

Comment: Just insert `aCols = Array()` before redimming, then you can check the `UBound(aCols) > -1`condition @YasserKhalil

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone for sharing these great ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Function safeUBound()` which looks ugly due to OERN but works fine:

```
Function safeUBound(a)
    
    safeUBound = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    safeUBound = UBound(a)
    
End Function
```

Another solution is to assign empty array or [empty 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569930/2165759) to the variable `aCols` either at the very beginning of the code or at userform initialize.